# Why are my unit tests not coming through when the original code works fine?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, repository, junit5

My unit test keeps on sending error messages even though the initial code works and I wrote other unit tests the same way and they work perfectly.

Initial code:

```
@Override
    public void newOrder(OrderVO orderVO) {

        OrderProduct orderProduct = new OrderProduct();

        Optional<User> userResponse = userRepository.findById(orderVO.getUserId());
        User user = userResponse.orElse(new User());
        Orders order = new Orders(user);
        orderRepository.save(order);

        orderProduct.setId(new OrderProductId());
        orderProduct.setOrders(order);

        List<ProductVO> productVOS = orderVO.getOrderProducts();
        for (ProductVO p : productVOS) {

            Optional<Product> productResponse = productRepository.findById(p.getId());
            Product product = productResponse.orElse(new Product());
            product.setAmount(product.getAmount() - p.getAmountOfOrderedProducts());
            product.setUser(user);
            productRepository.save(product);

            orderProduct.setProduct(product);
            orderProduct.setAmountOfOrderedProduct(p.getAmountOfOrderedProducts());
            orderProductRepository.saveOrder(orderProduct.getProduct().getId(), orderProduct.getOrders().getId(), orderProduct.getAmountOfOrderedProduct());
        }
    }
```

test:

```
@Test
    void newOrder() {

        User userTest = new User(1);
        Optional<User> optUserTest = Optional.of(userTest);
        Optional<Product> optProductTest = Optional.of(productTest);
        OrderVO orderVO = new OrderVO();
        Orders orders = new Orders(userTest);

        when(userRepository.findById(anyInt())).thenReturn(optUserTest);
        when(productRepository.findById(anyInt())).thenReturn(optProductTest);

        orderService.newOrder(orderVO);

        verify(productRepository, times(1)).save(productTest);
        verify(orderRepository, times(1)).save(orders);
        verify(orderProductRepository, times(1)).saveOrder(1,1,53);

    }
```

I keep on getting two errors:
first one is pointing to `verify(productRepository, times(1)).save(productTest);`
and says that

```
Wanted but not invoked:
productRepository.save(
    com.carlsberg.orderservice.domains.Product@a1db9da0
);
-> at com.carlsberg.orderservice.serviceImpl.OrderServiceImplTest.newOrder(OrderServiceImplTest.java:78)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Second one points to `verify(orderRepository, times(1)).save(orders);`
and the error message is

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
orderRepository.save(
    com.carlsberg.orderservice.domains.Orders@d7c7950f
);
```

The difference seems to be in `d7c7950f` part.

This is my first time trying to do unit testing. Really not sure why am I getting this errors since the same concept of writing unit tests worked just fine on other methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is due to the fact that your test never coverages a case where there are `ProductVo`s in tested `OrderVO`. That makes stubbing that method to be 'wrong' since the method is invoked only in a loop that goes through `ProductVO`s.

Try to add some `ProductVO`s if it helps for this. *Maybe you still might want to test with 0 1 and many `OrderVOs` in 0 case just remove the stubbing as it is not needed*

The second one is a bit more complicated, in touyr service you have:

```
Orders order = new Orders(user);
orderRepository.save(order);
```

on the other hand in your test you have:

```
Orders orders = new Orders(userTest);
```

the is no path that saves the **orders** you created in your test , it is alwasy created in the service and the hassh is thus also different. I guess this error goes away when you change verify to, say:

```
verify(orderRepository, times(1)).save(any());
```

but the test is bad and you should fix it to use the orders you create in test.

Comment: That helped a lot. Thanks for the effort.